# Anonymous named pipes over windows 7

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I am trying to build a server-client model using named pipes. Because I can't guarantee access to the server named pipe, I choose to use anonymous access to the server. So far, my model worked in any OS under vista, the integrity level keeps blocking write-access to my pipe-server.
I am using `S:(MN;;NW;;LW):D(A;;GA;;AN)`  for my security descriptor, but still can't get write access in windows 7.  When i use the same code and call `CreateFile` in win32api with `GENERIC_READ` it works.

If someone could post working code or explain to me the solution, I would be very grateful.

Comment: "Anonymous named" doesn't sound right now, does it?

Comment: It means the pipe is a named pipe, but the connection is Anonymous . sorry if I was unclear

Comment: For the Mandatory Integrity Label, `S:(MN;;NW;;LW)` should read `S:(ML;;NW;;LW)` - is that your problem, or was that just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, anonymous connection have untrusted integrity , instead of LW I should have write the Sid of untrusted integrity s-1-16-0 to get write access from anonymous connections